# Write a vector in terms of 2 other vectors

Tags: vectors

In the dagram ${\vec {AB}}$ and $\vec {BD}$ are representatives of vectors u and v respectively.  AD:DC = 2:1.

Find $\vec {BC}$ in terms of u and v.

[image]

I made the answer ${1\over 2} {(u + v)}$ as I would have thought covering half the distance but the answer in the book is ${1\over 2} {(u + 3v)}$.

I don't get why it is 3$v$.

Comment: Is there supposed to be a diagram included in this?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, picture added.

Comment: Working it out, I think you're missing some parentheses in your suggested answer and the correct answer; I'm getting $\vec{BC} = \frac{1}{2}(u + 3v)$.

Comment: but why 3v?  I think I am missing why it is 3v

Comment: Because $1 + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{3}{2}$? See the derivation in any of the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\vec{AD}=u+v$ so $\vec{DC}=\frac{1}{2}u + \frac{1}{2}v$

$\vec{BC}=v+\vec{DC}=v+\frac{1}{2}u + \frac{1}{2}v=\frac{1}{2}u+\frac{3}{2}v$

Answer (score 1):

$\vec{AD} = \vec{u} + \vec{v}$ by the definition of vector addition. Since $\vec{DC} = \frac{1}{2}\vec{AD}$, $\vec{AC} = \frac{3}{2}\vec{AD} = \frac{3}{2}(\vec{u} + \vec{v})$. $\vec{BC} = \vec{AC} - \vec{AB} = \frac{3}{2}(\vec{u} + \vec{v}) - \vec{u} = \frac{1}{2}\vec{u}+\frac{3}{2}\vec{v}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{cases}
\vec{BC}=\vec{v}+\vec{DC}\\
\vec{u}+\vec{v}=\vec{AD}
\end{cases}$$

And $\vec{DC}=\frac 1 2 \vec{AD}$ so $\vec{BC}=\vec{v}+\frac 1 2(\vec{u}+\vec{v}) = \frac{1}{2}\vec{u}+\frac{3}{2}\vec{v}$